# Magento 2 : override class

Tags: magento2

Is their any way to override "`Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper`" class in module ?

I want to override method in it.

```
private function convertToProductData(int $productId, array $indexData, int $storeId): array
```

I have tried
**Vendor\Elasticsearch\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper" type="Vendor\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper"/>
</config>
```

**app\code\Vendor\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper;

use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\DataProvider;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute;
use Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Document\Builder;
use Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapperInterface;
use Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapperInterface;
use Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldType\Date as DateFieldType;
use Magento\AdvancedSearch\Model\Adapter\DataMapper\AdditionalFieldsProviderInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface;

class ProductDataMapper extends \Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper
{
        /**
     * @var AttributeOptionInterface[]
     */
    private $attributeOptionsCache;

    /**
     * @var Builder
     */
    private $builder;

    /**
     * @var FieldMapperInterface
     */
    private $fieldMapper;

    /**
     * @var DateFieldType
     */
    private $dateFieldType;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $excludedAttributes;

    /**
     * @var AdditionalFieldsProviderInterface
     */
    private $additionalFieldsProvider;

    /**
     * @var DataProvider
     */
    private $dataProvider;

    /**
     * List of attributes which will be skipped during mapping
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $defaultExcludedAttributes = [
        'price',
        'media_gallery',
        'tier_price',
        'quantity_and_stock_status',
        'media_gallery',
        'giftcard_amounts',
    ];

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $attributesExcludedFromMerge = [
        'status',
        'visibility',
        'tax_class_id',
    ];

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $sortableAttributesValuesToImplode = [
        'name',
    ];

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $filterableAttributeTypes;

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $sortableCaseSensitiveAttributes = [
        'name',
    ];

    /**
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param FieldMapperInterface $fieldMapper
     * @param DateFieldType $dateFieldType
     * @param AdditionalFieldsProviderInterface $additionalFieldsProvider
     * @param DataProvider $dataProvider
     * @param array $excludedAttributes
     * @param array $sortableAttributesValuesToImplode
     * @param array $filterableAttributeTypes
     * @param array $sortableCaseSensitiveAttributes
     */
    public function __construct(
        Builder $builder,
        FieldMapperInterface $fieldMapper,
        DateFieldType $dateFieldType,
        AdditionalFieldsProviderInterface $additionalFieldsProvider,
        DataProvider $dataProvider,
        array $excludedAttributes = [],
        array $sortableAttributesValuesToImplode = [],
        array $filterableAttributeTypes = [],
        array $sortableCaseSensitiveAttributes = []
    ) {
        $this->builder = $builder;
        $this->fieldMapper = $fieldMapper;
        $this->dateFieldType = $dateFieldType;
        $this->excludedAttributes = array_merge($this->defaultExcludedAttributes, $excludedAttributes);
        $this->sortableAttributesValuesToImplode = array_merge(
            $this->sortableAttributesValuesToImplode,
            $sortableAttributesValuesToImplode
        );
        $this->additionalFieldsProvider = $additionalFieldsProvider;
        $this->dataProvider = $dataProvider;
        $this->attributeOptionsCache = [];
        $this->filterableAttributeTypes = $filterableAttributeTypes;
        $this->sortableCaseSensitiveAttributes = array_merge(
            $this->sortableCaseSensitiveAttributes,
            $sortableCaseSensitiveAttributes
        );
    }

        /**
     * Convert raw data retrieved from source tables to human-readable format.
     *
     * @param int $productId
     * @param array $indexData
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return array
     */
    private function convertToProductData(int $productId, array $indexData, int $storeId): array
    {
        echo'override working'; exit;
        $productAttributes = [];

        if (isset($indexData['options'])) {
            // cover case with "options"
            // see \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\DataProvider::prepareProductIndex
            $productAttributes['options'] = $indexData['options'];
            unset($indexData['options']);
        }

        foreach ($indexData as $attributeId => $attributeValues) {
            $attribute = $this->dataProvider->getSearchableAttribute($attributeId);
            if (in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $this->excludedAttributes, true)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!\is_array($attributeValues)) {
                $attributeValues = [$productId => $attributeValues];
            }
            $attributeValues = $this->prepareAttributeValues($productId, $attribute, $attributeValues, $storeId);
            $productAttributes += $this->convertAttribute($attribute, $attributeValues, $storeId);
        }

        return $productAttributes;
    }
}
```

Comment: updated question added code.

Answer (score 1):

1. create `di.xml` in to the following location

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper" />
</config>
```

2. create `ProductDataMapper.php` file on this location.

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/Model/Adapter/BatchDataMapper/ProductDataMapper.php

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper;

class ProductDataMapper extends \Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Model Rewrite Working"; die();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir & how to override convertToProductData method in the same class ?

Comment: if you are able to see "Model Rewrite Working" then copy paste vendor's method in your overrided file and add your custom code as per your need

Comment: no need of any constructor & properties define above constructor ?
i have added file content in question.

Comment: simple you can first copt the code of that file here except the file namespace, then modify the code according to your requirement.

Comment: I have done that, please have a look at the file code which i have added in question. but its not working.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addField() on null in /var/www/html/local.dollskill.com/public_html/dollskill_magentoreplatform/Magento2/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/BatchDataMapper/ProductDataMapper.php:153

Comment: Do not modify the Orignal Question, if you have new issues then ask the question seprately so other community member also can help you int that one.